# How to calculate coordinates of ball when collided with a wall?

Tags: game-mechanics, linear-algebra

I'm developing a game like bubble shooter and need to implement bounce of ball off the vertical wall. I have the following inputs:

1. Starting position of bubble: `{left: 382, right: 378}`
2. Firing angle in radians: `1.34`
3. Game board sizes: `{width: 760, height: 620}`.

I have two walls to the left side of the bubble and to the right side of the bubble.

How could I calculate bubble's center point coordinates to stop it on collided left of right wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simpler way would be to find the collision between the ray caster from the center of the bubble to two imaginary walls which are 1: left wall moved to the right by the radius of the bubble and 2: right wall moved to the left by the radius of the bubble.

The point where this ray (center of the bubble) hits any of the two imaginary walls will be the point where the bubble hits the real walls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you provide some formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
¬¬